# Testing whether an expression is an integer

Tags: polynomials, expression-test

The following is based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505618/show-that-a35a-is-an-integer) which shows mathematically that if

$$a = \sqrt[3]{1 + \sqrt{\frac{152}{27}}}- \sqrt[3]{-1 + \sqrt{\frac{152}{27}}}$$

then

$$a^3 + 5 a$$

is an integer.

In *Mathematica*, though, the result does not hold:

```
a = Power[1 + Sqrt[152/27], (3)^-1] - Power[-1 + Sqrt[152/27], (3)^-1];

IntegerQ[a^3 + 5 a]
```

(* False *)

How can we "prove" or compute the proper result?

Comment: Using `IntegerQ[FullSimplify[a^3+5*a]]` gives `True`. Relevant quote from the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerQ.html): "`IntegerQ[expr]` returns `False` unless `expr` is manifestly an integer (i.e. has head `Integer`)". In the "Possible Issues" section of the documentation, this kind of problem is discussed for `GoldenRatio - 1/GoldenRatio`.

Comment: Thanks.  That does it!

Comment: I vastly prefer using `AlgebraicNumber[]` for these sorts of things: `IntegerQ[AlgebraicNumber[Power[1 + Sqrt[152/27], 1/3] - Power[-1 + Sqrt[152/27], 1/3], CoefficientList[a^3 + 5 a, a]]]`.

Comment: A bit disappointing that `ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"][a^3 + 5*a]` splats.

Answer (score 7):

A couple more ways:

```
ToNumberField[a^3 + 5a] ∈ Integers
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
AlgebraicIntegerQ[a^3 + 5a] && Exponent[MinimalPolynomial[a^3 + 5a, x], x] == 1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  Your first solution is particularly valuable.  ($+1$)

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = (1 + Sqrt[152/27])^(1/3) - (-1 + Sqrt[152/27])^(1/3);
```

Use [`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html)

```
a^3 + 5 a // RootReduce

(* 2 *)
```

Or [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
a^3 + 5 a // FullSimplify

(* 2 *)
```

Comment: Yep... and then perform `IntegerQ`...